# How to make it efficient in java

Tags: java

I try to make a simple calculator, like in the Picture below. but I want to write:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                         
        number1 = Integer.parseInt(n1.getText());
        number2 = Integer.parseInt(n2.getText());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,(number1+number2));
```

This code in every button So how could i do it by declaring in a common place

[image]

Comment: Create an abstract class and use inheritance. Or create a class and use composition. Or use the observer pattern. Or the decorator pattern. Or the strategy pattern (oh wait that's composition). Plenty of choices. My advice; look into composition and the strategy pattern. It's written detailed and simple in the Head first Design Pattern book. Can't write an example on my phone though. Sorry 

Answer (score 2):

How about some simple helper methods?

```
private int getNumber1() {
    return Integer.parseInt(n1.getText());
}
private int getNumber2() {
    return Integer.parseInt(n2.getText());
}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                         
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, getNumber1() + getNumber2());
}
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                         
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, getNumber1() - getNumber2());
}
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                         
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, getNumber1() * getNumber2());
}
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                         
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, getNumber1() / getNumber2());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define an enum for the operations:

```
enum Operation {
  PLUS {
    @Override int operate(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
  },
  MINUS {
    @Override int operate(int a, int b) { return a - b; }
  },
  // etc, for others.
  ;

  abstract int operate(int a, int b);
}
```

Then define an `ActionListener` subclass which takes an `Operation` as a parameter:

```
class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
  final Operation operation;

  MyActionListener(Operation operation) {
    this.operation = operation;
  }

  @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    int a = Integer.parseInt(n1.getText());
    int b = Integer.parseInt(n2.getText());
    int result = operation.operate(a, b);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, result);
  }
}
```

Then add an instance of this class as an event listener to each button:

```
jButton1.addActionListener(new MyActionListener(Operation.PLUS));
jButton2.addActionListener(new MyActionListener(Operation.MINUS));
```